# How to get timezone from time string

Tags: ios, timezone, nsdate, nstimezone

`NSDate` class doesn't store information about timezones. I have to store `NSTimeZone` separately. I can't find any way to get timezone from string like: `"2015-01-09T00:00:00+02:00"` or `"2015-01-09T02:00:00Z` . Could you help me please?

Comment: Yes I see"+02:00" Z is equivalent of "00:00"

Comment: In general, you can't.  Read "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using library for formatting Date data format. I can recommend ISO8601 date formatter - https://github.com/boredzo/iso-8601-date-formatter and using it's `[dateFormatter dateComponentsFromString:` method to get `NSDateComponents`

Edit:

Just to include example with metioned library:

```
ISO8601DateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[ISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.includeTime = YES;
NSString *testTime = @"2015-01-09T00:00:00+02:00";
NSTimeZone *timeZone;
NSDateComponents *components = [dateFormatter dateComponentsFromString:testTime timeZone:&timeZone];
```

Produces:

```
Printing description of timeZone:
GMT+0200 (GMT+2) offset 7200
```